# Find limit of sum $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\sum^{n}_{k=1}k^2a_k$

Tags: calculus

If $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n = A$, find $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\sum^{n}_{k=1}k^2a_k\right)$$

Any hints? I thought that I can interchange $\lim$ with sum, but I think that it is not true, because I don't know type of convergence of sum. Also, I know that $\sum a_k$ should converge because $\sum^{n}_{k=1}k^2a_k$ exists. But how to proceed from here?

Comment: Finite sums $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2a_k$ always exist, but that tells you nothing about the convergence of $\sum a_k.$

Comment: This limit can be found using the theorem: Of $b_n$ is a sequence converging to $L$ then and $$c_n=\frac{b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n}{n},$$ then $c_n\to L,$ also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can interchange $a_k$ with its limit $A$,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^nk^2 a_k - \frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^nk^2A\right| = 0.$$

To see this, let $\varepsilon>0$. First note, that $|a_k|\le C$ for some $C$. Moreover, let $K>0$ such that $|a_k-A|\le \varepsilon$ for all $k\ge K$. Then, for $n\ge K$ there holds

\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^nk^2 a_k - \frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^nk^2A\right| & \le \frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^N k^2|(a_k-A)| + \frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=N+1}^n k^2|a_k-A|\\
&\le \frac{K^3(|A|+C)}{n^3} + \frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 \varepsilon \le \frac{K^3(|A|+C)}{n^3} + \varepsilon \le 2\varepsilon
\end{align*}

for $n$ sufficiently large. Therefore the limit is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^nk^2 a_k = A/3$.

Answer (score 2):

Denote the partial sums with $s_n = \sum^{n}_{k=1}k^2a_k$ and apply the [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem):
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{s_n}{n^3} =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{s_n - s_{n-1}}{n^3 - (n-1)^3}
$$
holds if the limit on the right exists, which is the case:
$$
 \frac{s_n - s_{n-1}}{n^3 - (n-1)^3} =  \frac{n^2 a_n}{n^3 - (n-1)^3}
=  \frac{n^2 }{3 n^2 - 3n +1}a_n \to \frac 13 A
$$
for $n \to \infty$.

This is also valid if the sequence $(a_n)$ diverges to $+\infty$ or to $-\infty$.

Comment: I’m not doubting your answer, but my answer, using a very limited version of Stolz-Cesàsro, is different, (I get $A/6,$) and I can’t find the flaw in either.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \sim \frac 13 n^3$, so you get $A/3$ as well.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot basic math.

Answer (score 1):

There is a general theorem:

> If $b_n$ is a sequence and $b_n\to L.$ Let: $$c_n=\frac{b_1+\cdots+b_n}{n}.$$
> Then $c_n\to L.$

In this problem, let $b_n$ be the sequence:

$$a_1,a_2,a_2,a_2,a_2,\underbrace{a_3,\dots,a_3}_{9 \text{ times}},\dots,  \underbrace{a_k,\dots,a_k}_{k^2\text{ times}},\dots$$

Then we get, from the theorem, that:

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nk^2a_k}{\sum_{k=1}^nk^2}\to A.$$

Then you need to compute the limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n k^2$$

---

The theorem above is used in [Cesàro summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation), and it is a special case of the Stolz-Cesàro theorem, used in another answer.